# Does Solaris have an equivalent to /etc/ld.so.conf?

Tags: solaris, configuration, libraries, dynamic-linking

I compiled a package for Solaris 11 Express that has some library dependencies, which I also compiled from source and installed in the usual /usr/local. (And Solaris doesn't even *have* /usr/local pre-created!) So, my program runs correctly, but I have to run it with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./myprogram
```

or it complains that it couldn't find libsomething.so.

How do I include /usr/local/lib in the library search path, system-wide? Linux has /etc/ld.so.conf -- Solaris doesn't.

Comment: "And Solaris doesn't even have /usr/local pre-created!" Why would it ? This directory violates the SVR4 file system standard. "man filesystem" for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the section about setting up the linker: http://bwachter.lart.info/solaris/solfaq.html

You want the [`crle`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2239/crle-1/index.html) command.

Comment: When you cite an external source, it's a good idea to put the gist of it in your post, in case the link disappears.

Comment: @Gilles: Good point.  I'll remember that in the future.  Thanks

Comment: "crle" is both risky and somewhat overkill as the binary won't work out of the box on other OS instances unless you run crle on all of them. The recommended way is to set the run path in one or other methods suggested in the other reply.

Answer (score 3):

If it's acceptable for you, you can set a library search path when compiling (more precisely, when linking). Pass the `-rpath` option to `ld`, or tell the compiler to do so, e.g.

```
gcc -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Equivalently, set `LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib` when compiling.